# Error Document not displayed when URL contains directoy

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this problem. When I access exampleSite.com/unexistingpage.php everything is ok and Error document is displayed. However, when I try to browser exampleSite.com/folder/unexistingpage.php some broken variation of the home page is displayed and the Error Document is not found (I think the site tries to find it in the /folder/ directory)

In my .htaccess I have the following

```
ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

So how can I fix this and tell the site to look for the error document only in the root directory? Or maybe something else causes the problem?

PS: I'm on Apache 2.4

Comment: `some broken variation of the home page is displayed ` - so you don't get `/404.php` displayed when URL is `exampleSite.com/folder/unexistingpage.php` ?

Comment: No, I get an html version of the home page and in the Console I get ""NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://exampleSite.com/folder/unexistingpage.php" This is caused only when a directory is added to the url, otherwise everything works

Comment: Do you have another htaccess in /folder?

Comment: For testing change `404` line to this: `ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/404.php` and then visit `domain.com/folder/unexistingpage.php` to see if this makes any difference

Comment: Yes, this works :) Thanks! Is there any way to write it without the exact url?

Comment: ok so in that case `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` is also working fine but most likely your css/js/images are not found due to relative paths. For testing again you can just add `<h1>This is 404 page</h1>` in the `404.php` and see if that works.

Comment: Ou! You are right!!! Thank you! You can write some really simple answer to mark it as the right one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating my comment into an answer.

It appears `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` directive is working fine but most likely your `css/js/images` are not found due to your use relative paths in `404.php` file.

For testing you can just add `<h1>This is 404 page</h1>` in the `/404.php` and that should display big bold `This is 404 page` text from all the non existing pages.

To fix the issue you can add this just below `<head>` section of your `404.php` page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the <base href="/"> Really useful!